# Selecting a class in the same div but not others

Tags: jquery

I have an app that has red-wines and wines. If something is selected as a red-wine, the corresponding wine in that and only that div, should be set to checked and set to disabled. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z5FYR/

Basically, is there a way for me to limit the scope (and not internal divs - like basically this 'subs' but nothing else)? Or should I make a secondary thing to select off of like a data-id='23' or something?

thx

**edit #1**
So there are three instances of 'is-wine' that are demarcated by inclusion in that '.subs' class. I want to select only the one that is in the same div and not the other two.

Comment: Am I wrong or this is the right place to use radio buttons? BTW your HTML looks mal-formatted: shouldn't it be like: http://jsfiddle.net/z5FYR/1/

Comment: it looks like you already are limiting the scope by using `.parent().find(...)`. Is it not working the way you want it to?

Comment: @roko the .subs class is nested so that's actually what is intended

Comment: @timpone well, Diode just answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try jQuery siblings

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

```
$(this).siblings('input.is-wine').attr("checked", this.checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

html

```
 <div class='subs'>
        wine<input type='checkbox' class='is-wine' />
        red wine<input type='checkbox' class='is-red-wine' />
    </div>

      <div class='subs'>
        wine<input type='checkbox' class='is-wine' />
        red wine<input type='checkbox' class='is-red-wine' />
          </div>  

        <div class='subs'>
        wine<input type='checkbox' class='is-wine' />
        red wine<input type='checkbox' class='is-red-wine' />

        </div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.is-red-wine').on('change', function(){
       //alert('this changed');
       $(this).parent().find('input.is-wine').attr('checked','status');
        $(this).parent().find('input.is-wine').attr('disabled',true);
    });
});
```

Comment: No, it's not.  If you check "red-wine" in the first row, all the "wine"s get checked - only the one in the same row should be checked, based on the description in the question

Comment: Oh I just noticed you commented that you need the subs div to be nested. In this case Diode's answer is the correct one.